# Fixing the Block If without End If error

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am just getting started with Macros and VB but have some experience with Excel formulas. My problem is my excel formulas are becoming very long and complicated and I thought VB could help me.

I have a lot of financial data that I would like to categorize in a column. My first step is to categorize particular companies as either a private company or a warrant. I get a 'block if without end if' error with the below code. I have tried various things but no luck.

```
    Range("F2:F400") = "Private Company"
Else If Range("A2:A400") = "Company B" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Private Company"
Else If Range("A2:A400") = "Company C" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Private Company"
Else If Range("A2:A400") = "Company D" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Warrant"
Else If Range("A2:A400") = "Company E" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Warrant"
Else If Range("A2:A400") = "Company F" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Warrant"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You've got a few issues here.  I think you can clear up the block if without end if error by changing your `Else If` to `ElseIf`.  I don't know if that's the logic you want though.  Also you can't compare a range of more than one cell (`Range("A2:A400")`) to a single value though.  You'll end up with a Type Mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

You can either nest a new `If ... End If` inside an `Else` clause or use the `ElseIf` version (there is no space). For the former, your code would need to be:

```
If Range("A2:A400") = "Company A" Then 
    Range("F2:F400") = "Private Company" 
Else 
    If Range("A2:A400") = "Company B" Then 
        Range("F2:F400") = "Private Company" 
    Else 
        If Range("A2:A400") = "Company C" Then 
            Range("F2:F400") = "Private Company" 
        Else 
            If Range("A2:A400") = "Company D" Then 
                Range("F2:F400") = "Warrant" 
            Else 
                If Range("A2:A400") = "Company E" Then 
                    Range("F2:F400") = "Warrant" 
                Else 
                    If Range("A2:A400") = "Company F" Then 
                        Range("F2:F400") = "Warrant" 
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Indentation added for ease of readability.

Also you'll need to test every cell within the range "A2:A400" separately. Like:

```
For Each cell In Range("A2:A400")
    If cell.Value = "" Then
    Else
        ...
    End If
Next cell
```

A simpler method might be to create a lookup table of company names and whether private or warrant and then a VLOOKUP function in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, `Else If` is nested conditions, where `ElseIf` is cascading:

Try this:

```
If Range("A2:A400") = "Company A" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Private Company"
ElseIf Range("A2:A400") = "Company B" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Private Company"
ElseIf Range("A2:A400") = "Company C" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Private Company"
ElseIf Range("A2:A400") = "Company D" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Warrant"
ElseIf Range("A2:A400") = "Company E" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Warrant"
ElseIf Range("A2:A400") = "Company F" Then
    Range("F2:F400") = "Warrant"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

i also wanted to add that you can use (this is just ChipsLetten extended a bit so you can see how it works)

```
Sub ColumnLoop()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A400")
            For Each cell In rng
                Debug.Print cell.Address
                    If (cell.Value = "Company A" Or cell.Value = "Company B" Or cell.Value = "Company B") Then
                       cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Private"
                        Debug.Print cell.Address
                    Else
                        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Warrant"
                         Debug.Print cell.Address
                    End If
                Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: screw me for no comments

Comment: No comments on Stack Overflow can be considered a good thing sometimes lol